# LinearLayoutが霞む

Tags: android, android-studio, xml

先日オープンβでリリースしたアプリのお問い合わせで、「ラベルが滲んでいる」との指摘をいただきました。

[image: 症状]
特に凝ったことはしていないのですが、以下問題部分を抜粋しました
連絡くださったユーザーさんの端末はd社のXperiaZ3とのことです。
自身の端末(HTL23)では発生しておらず機種依存によるものと思われるのですが、
対策方法はあるのでしょうか。

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:rotation="-4"
    android:background="#ffc1571d">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

以上よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 同じ端末があったので該当コードを試してみましたが、現象は再現しませんでした

Comment: @Shintaro  わざわざ検証していただいてありがとうございます。個体差によるものなのかもしれませんね。一旦このままにしておいて報告が多いようであれば別の表示方法を考えたいと思います。